# How to use variable integer value in withColumn

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have created dataframe to get `MaxRecordId` as integer value from the table as below.

```
val MaxRecordID = DF.agg(max("RecordID"))
```

Now, I have to use this `MaxRecordID` in `withColumn` as below:

```
Df2.withColumn("RecordID", MaxRecordID)
```

but this is not giving correct result, getting 'MaxRecordID:Int' but I need value of `MaxRecordID`

how to pass `MaxRecordID` in above statement.

Also, tried below:

```
Df2.withColumn("RecordID", lit(MaxRecord))
```

but getting error as:

> feature is not supported: Literal for '[MaxRecordID: int]

Is there way to pass this variable integer value in `withColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `MaxRecordID` is not an `Int`, but a `Dataframe`. If you want to take the value, you'll need to use `.head` and the `getInt` method like so:

```
val df = Seq(10, 102, 103, 1003).toDF("RecordID")

val aggregated_df = df.agg(max("RecordID"))
aggregated_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max(RecordID): int]

val maxRecordId = aggregated_df.head.getInt(0)
maxRecordId: Int = 1003
```

and then you can use

```
df.withColumn("myMaxColumn", lit(maxRecordId)).show()
+--------+-----------+
|RecordID|myMaxColumn|
+--------+-----------+
|      10|       1003|
|     102|       1003|
|     103|       1003|
|    1003|       1003|
+--------+-----------+
```